# ontapp() method in map view

Tags: android, android-mapview

im new in android and working in map view i want to get location,s logi/lati from map by tapping on a location , Google take me to this method 
**protected  boolean onTapp(GeoPoint p, MapView map) {

```
  if(Map == null) {
   Map = map;
  }
   Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this.mContext,Locale.getDefault());
   try {


    List<Address> aList = coder.getFromLocation(p.getLatitudeE6()/1e6, p.getLongitudeE6()/1e6, 5);
    if(aList.size() > 0) {
     int i = 0;
     String address = "";

     while(aList.get(0).getAddressLine(i) != null) {
      address+=aList.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + " ";
      i++;
     }


    }
   }
    catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return true;**
```

i have Add this on ItemizedOverlay with little change but its not working can any one will please help me or share some working example of it.

Answer (score 0):

this will do...
                                                                                                      aList = geocoder.getFromLocation(pt.getLatitudeE6()/1E6, pt.getLongitudeE6()/1E6, 1);

```
              if(aList != null) {
               Address returnedAddress = aList.get(0);
               StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("\n");
               for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
               }
               getlocfrommap.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
              }
              else{
              getlocfrommap.setText("No Address returned!");
              }
             } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
              getlocfrommap.setText("Canont get Address!");
```